# Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org"... Failed to download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json

Tags: server, gnome, updates, software-center

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday and ran updates which appeared to complete succesfully. Today I tried to run updates (not expecting any to be found) and received this message in my software center. [update center screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKG9d.png)

The error message I received was exactly as follows, was too long to post exactly in the subject line:

> Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org":[*/*/*/source/shell-extensions*/] Failed to download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json: Service Unavailable:

I have not found this exact problem listed in my searches and do not understand it well enough to know what it means. Sounds like it is an issue on the server download end. My internet is working.

Comment: Far as I know... it's a bug. Dismiss it, and/or restart Software Center.