# Install Chromium from Software Center

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, software-center, chromium

(1) Network works fine

(2) In Software Center, search doesn't work, search anything gives no result.

(3) Chromium install failed: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open...

Then I've installed Chromium successfully from command line.

Is there a way to install application from the Software Center (**not command line**)? How to fix the Software Center problems?

**Update**:

After reboot Chromium can be removed and reinstalled in Software Center, but search still doesn't work, and update doesn't work as [Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org"... Failed to download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218828/unable-to-download-updates-from-extensions-gnome-org-failed-to-download-htt)

Comment: After (2) I goto communication tab and sort by name then it is there

Comment: @karel How is this question linked to that question?

Comment: @karel This question is about Software Center, not cmdline, "Then I've installed Chromium successfully from command line...Is there a way to install application from the Software Center (not command line)?" - It is linked, but not a duplication

Comment: Still get the problem, now solved by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557413/unable-to-acquire-the-dpkg-frontend-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-are-you